# Usuário que tenha permissão para criar outros usuário SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Estou tentando usar um usuário que não seja o SA para criar novos usuários em uma base SQL Server 2014, já tentei as roles **db_accessadmin** e **db_securityadmin**, mas elas não dão permissões para alterar outras roles.

Por exemplo, quando crio um usuário, quero permitir as roles **db_datareader** e **db_datawriter** para este usuário, mas não tenho permissões.

Enfim, alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer inserir novos usuários no servidor (Server > Security > Logins) ou novos num determinado banco (Server > Databases > BancoTeste > Security > Users) em questão (observe que o usuário já deverá existir no servidor)?

Comment: A nível de banco, quero poder logar com um usuários que não seja SA e então criar outros usuário e designar roles para eles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder criar um login você precisa de uma das seguintes permissões
`ALTER ANY LOGIN` ou `ALTER LOGIN`
Para criar o usuário você vai precisar da seguinte permissão `ALTER ANY USER`

O login é para ele se conectar ao servidor enquanto o usuário é para permitir o login se conectar ao Database.